# <MYSQL JOIN QUERY> How to group after sorting?

Tags: mysql, join

There is a table that stores product information.

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `idx` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `reg_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
)
```

And there is an image table for a specific product.

```
CREATE TABLE `fileData` 
 (
    `idx` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `file_url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci', 
    `p_idx` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'product idx',
    `imgNum` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'fileCount',
    `regdate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idx`) 
)
```

### fileData

| idx | file_url | p_idx | imgNum | regdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9474 | /pic/1634705274249.png | 2323 | 3 | 2021-10-20 13:47:54 |
| 9475 | /pic/1634705274250.png | 2323 | 4 | 2021-10-20 13:47:54 |
| 9476 | /pic/1634705274251.png | 2323 | 1 | 2021-10-20 13:47:54 |
| 9477 | /pic/1634705274284.png | 2323 | 2 | 2021-10-20 13:47:54 |
| 9478 | /pic/1634705274288.png | 2323 | 5 | 2021-10-20 13:47:54 |
| 9469 | /pic/1634611885861.jpeg | 2322 | 1 | 2021-10-19 11:51:26 |
| 9470 | /pic/1634611885862.jpeg | 2322 | 2 | 2021-10-19 11:51:26 |
| 9471 | /pic/1634611885862.jpeg | 2322 | 3 | 2021-10-19 11:51:26 |
| 9472 | /pic/1634611885863.jpeg | 2322 | 4 | 2021-10-19 11:51:26 |
| 9473 | /pic/1634611885864.jpeg | 2322 | 5 | 2021-10-19 11:51:26 |
| 9464 | /pic/1634549314931.jpeg | 2321 | 1 | 2021-10-18 18:28:35 |
| 9465 | /pic/1634549314932.jpeg | 2321 | 2 | 2021-10-18 18:28:35 |
| 9466 | /pic/1634549314932.jpeg | 2321 | 3 | 2021-10-18 18:28:35 |
| 9467 | /pic/1634549314933.jpeg | 2321 | 4 | 2021-10-18 18:28:35 |
| 9468 | /pic/1634549314933.jpeg | 2321 | 5 | 2021-10-18 18:28:35 |
| 9425 | /pic/1634544307500.png | 2314 | 4 | 2021-10-18 17:05:07 |
| 9426 | /pic/1634544307501.png | 2314 | 2 | 2021-10-18 17:05:07 |
| 9427 | /pic/1634544307517.png | 2314 | 3 | 2021-10-18 17:05:07 |
| 9428 | /pic/1634544307518.png | 2314 | 1 | 2021-10-18 17:05:07 |
| 9429 | /pic/1634544307522.png | 2314 | 5 | 2021-10-18 17:05:07 |
| 9424 | /pic/1634108899663.png | 2310 | 7 | 2021-10-13 16:08:20 |

The administrator may change the order of the product image after registering the product.
When the order is changed, the data in the database is also reconstructed according to each order.
Items with imgNum 1 are being used as thumbnails.
*And the number of images registered in each product must be displayed.

I want to join the two tables and get the necessary results. Or is there a good solution other than join?

```
SELECT f.imgNum, count(f.idx) AS img_cnt, p.reg_date
FROM fileData AS f           
JOIN products AS p ON p.idx = f.p_idx
GROUP BY p.idx
ORDER BY p.reg_date DESC
```

### Result:

| p_idx | imgNum | file_url | img_cnt | reg_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2323 | 3 | /pic/1634705274249.png | 5 | 2021-10-20 13:47:54 |
| 2322 | 1 | /pic/1634611885861.jpeg | 5 | 2021-10-19 11:51:26 |
| 2321 | 1 | /pic/1634549314931.jpeg | 5 | 2021-10-18 18:28:35 |
| 2314 | 4 | /pic/1634544307500.png | 5 | 2021-10-18 17:05:08 |
| 2313 | 4 | /pic/1632375026407.gif | 5 | 2021-09-23 14:30:27 |
| 2311 | 1 | /pic/1630545720418.jpeg | 5 | 2021-09-02 10:22:01 |
| 2312 | 1 | /pic/1631586395031.png | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:22:01 |
| 2310 | 1 | /pic/1630465597465.gif | 7 | 2021-09-01 12:06:38 |

### The expected result:

| p_idx | imgNum | file_url | img_cnt | reg_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2323 | 1 | /pic/1634705274245.png | 5 | 2021-10-20 13:47:54 |
| 2322 | 1 | /pic/1634611885861.jpeg | 5 | 2021-10-19 11:51:26 |
| 2321 | 1 | /pic/1634549314931.jpeg | 5 | 2021-10-18 18:28:35 |
| 2314 | 1 | /pic/1634544307400.png | 5 | 2021-10-18 17:05:08 |
| 2313 | 1 | /pic/1632375026400.gif | 5 | 2021-09-23 14:30:27 |
| 2311 | 1 | /pic/1630545720418.jpeg | 5 | 2021-09-02 10:22:01 |
| 2312 | 1 | /pic/1631586395031.png | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:22:01 |
| 2310 | 1 | /pic/1630465597465.gif | 7 | 2021-09-01 12:06:38 |

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that gets the counts, rather than doing the count after the join.

```
SELECT f.p_idx, f.imgNum, c.img_cnt, p.reg_date
FROM fileData AS f           
JOIN products AS p ON p.idx = f.p_idx
JOIN (
    SELECT p_idx, COUNT(*) AS img_cnt
    FROM fileData
    GROUP BY p_idx
) AS c ON f.p_idx = c.p_idx
WHERE f.imgNum = 1
ORDER BY p.reg_date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Barmar.
It works well!